# How do I point my domain name to wso2 application

Tags: wso2, wso2-cloud

I have created a java application on http://wso2.com/. 
they have assigned a custom url

http://roaster.techgeeks.wso2apps.com

I tried to add me own domain name. but I always get "Fail to verify custom URL. 
" error.

How do I configure my domain to point to this application.
do I have to set DNS or CNAME, if yes, what are they?

PS: do not ask to set url redirection. ;)

[image: I had made this entry]

Answer (score 0):

[This document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AppCloud/Change+the+Default+Production+URL) 
explains how to configure your own URL for the apps hosted in [WSO2 APP Cloud](https://apps.cloud.wso2.com/). This should answer your questions..

Comment: Thanks for the reply but after making the CNAME entry, my domain still does not point to wso2 servers.

Comment: please see the attached screenshot of the cname entry. It is as specified by the doc?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about apps hosted on [WSO2 App Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/app-cloud):

Your screenshot seems to show wrong value specified as the CNAME record **Name**.

The **name** of the record should be your custom domain: e.g. myapp.mydomain.com. The **target** indeed should be the wso2 URL: in your case roaster.techgeeks.wso2apps.com.